# Upsherin at ​​2

Tags: minhag, minor-katan-child, chasidut-hasidism, age, upsherin

Why do [*Chernobyl*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_(Hasidic_dynasty))* chasidim do [*upsherin*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8212/3073) at the [**beginning**](http://asimplejew.blogspot.ca/2007/01/my-research-question-of-week.html#c116827861771715033) of the third year?

​* Including [*Trink*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisk_(Hasidic_dysnasty)), [*Skver*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skver_(Hasidic_dynasty)), etc.

Comment: Skevers do this too; their rationale is to get the child used to wearing a kippah, which presumably is not done prior to upsherin, before they start wearing a tallit katan.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Presumably?

Comment: I don't honestly know, at least when it comes to kippot and the wearing thereof

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Taspores 2:1:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46552&st=&pgnum=35) says the source of those who do it at 2 is based on [Braishis 21:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=261) "Vayigdal Hayeled" and Rashi says that was at 24 months. Also [Shmuel-1 1:22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=11).