Cutting hair prior to 3 years old
I have a son who just turned 2. When he was born, we decided to not cut his hair until three years old. I understand that this is more of a tradition rather than a "Jewish law" to do so.
The problem is this: his hair is incredibly thick and coarse and even after washing, it goes back to being knotted as soon as it dries. Combing his hair is incredibly painful for him. And I don't want to imagine another year of screaming and crying. I don't think it's fair to him.
Are there any thoughts on an "early Upsherin?" Are there any writings that tell us we should not do this?
Thank you

As you said it is only a minhag (a custom). There is no inherent problem with choosing to cut his hair early...

duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82410/759

German Jews have the custom to cut a boys hair at such point that it is long enough to need cutting. Prior to WW2 many non-Chasidic Eastern European Jews did this also.

I think most non-Chasidic Ashkenazim still don't do upsherin
