# According to Halacha, does one have to bury teeth?

Tags: halacha, medicine, funeral-burial-levaya, face

Is there a halachic obligation to bury teeth that have fallen out, just as one buries other body parts that become detached?

If not, why?
Does the same apply to detached skin? Or hair?

Related: [Do surgically removed body parts require Kevurah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/do-surgically-removed-body-parts-require-kevurah)
(I think this is different from the other question because teeth are more "transient" (similar to hair) than other body parts, therefore more likely not to require burial.)

Comment: I'm kind of expecting the answer to be no, but I didn't want to assume anything.

Comment: I wonder if the answer is different for baby teeth vs. adult teeth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See question #533 over [here](http://halachafortoday.com/questions-answers/qa11/):

> Many contemporary Poskim rule that teeth that fall out or are extracted  may simply be discarded and do not require burial or any other special treatment. There is no difference between adults and children or between baby teeth or permanent teeth.
>
> See [Shu"t Mishneh Halachos  Vol. 16 Siman 113](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1888&st=&pgnum=333) where he brings some opinions of special handling necessary for extracted baby teeth. He also writes a story  about the Noda B'Yehuda requiring burial for teeth.
>
> For Halacha L'Ma'aseh a Rav should be consulted.