# If my teeth are extracted, are they conisder shaimos?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shemot 13:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=178) says:

למען תהיה תורח ה בפיך

> So that G-d's Torah should be in your mouth.

So, my teeth are in my mouth together with the Torah, and they absorbed some of the Torah, too. So, I guess they are now considered "holy". If they are extracted from my mouth, and they have Torah on them, don't I have to bury them properly?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: not in jest: https://books.google.com/books?id=zI6qyWsUoacC&lpg=PA138&ots=CbHGKhdsmt&dq=tooth%20falls%20out%20minhag%20mouse&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q=tooth%20falls%20out%20minhag%20mouse&f=false

Comment: Related (non-PTIJ) question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10185

Answer (score 4):

Of course your teeth do not absorb torah -- just like they don't absorb milk or meat (otherwise you'd have to kasher them in between), so they are not shaimos

Comment: +1 despite that not being 100% correct. I think SA and other places say that if you have meat stuck between your teeth, you should not eat cheese until you floss away the meat. Then, of course, you need a fleishig garbage can for the floss, but that's a separate problem. BTW - your M.Y. name has some interesting possibilities :-)

Comment: but if there's no mamashus in your teeth there's no issue with taam like there would be with dishes, right? (I'm glad you like my name, thanks)

Comment: @DanF Fleischig garbage can‽

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt usually, the test for what is food is if a dog would eat it. Ever see a dog go through garbage?

Comment: @DanF, good point, although well-trained ones won't

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The explanation is as follows. Is a non Jewish janitor in a Yeshiva, who is together with the Torah learning boys, considered Shaimos?